# How do I update an object's members using a dict?

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a Django app that performs various functions, including inserting, or updating new records into the database via the URL.

So some internal application sends off a request to `/import/?a=1&b=2&c=3`, for example.
In the view, I want to create a new object, `foo = Foo()` and have the members of `foo` set to the data in the request.GET dictionary.

Here is what I'm doing now:

1. Request sent to `/import/?a=1&b=2&c=3`
2. View creates new object: `foo = Foo()`
3. Object is updated with data.

Here is what I got thus far:

```
foo.a = request['a']
foo.b = request['b']
foo.c = request['c']
```

Obviously this is tedious and error prone. The data in the URL has the exact same name as the object's members so it is a simple 1-to-1 mapping.

Ideally, I would like to do able to do something like this:

```
foo = Foo()
foo.update(request.GET)
```

or something to that effect.

Thanks!

Comment: The solution presented by Ants does what you want but how are you handling validation and type conversion?  Or are neither of concern (I find this hard to believe).

Comment: They're of no concern. This is being used entirely in house, where data is inserted into one database (with validation) and then (here) inserted into another.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the setattr function to dynamically set attributes:

```
for key,value in request.GET.items():
    setattr(foo, key, value)
```

Comment: Thanks. I must have had a brain fart because I looked over the documentation built-in functions.

Comment: You may want to swap `a_dict` with `request` and `obj` with `foo` to match Nick's code.

Answer (score 3):

If `request.GET` is a dictionary and `class Foo` does not use `__slots__`, then this should also work:

```
# foo is a Foo instance
foo.__dict__.update(request.GET)
```

Comment: This works in Django 1.6 with a true dict object. I didn't try request.GET or .POST.

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got it.

```
foo = Foo(**request.GET)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: The keywords may be coming through as unicode causing that error. something to look for... This code worked for me with three different ways of writting __init__()

Comment: That does not solve use case of updating an existing model with a dict of new values.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this to create a model object that then gets persisted, I'd strongly recommend using a [ModelForm](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/forms/modelforms/). This would do what you described, in the canonical way for Django, with the addition of validation.

To expand -- I didn't mean to use it for form output, just form input. As follows:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
      a = models.CharField(max_length=255),
      b = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
          model = Foo

def insert_foo(request):
      form = FooForm(request.GET)
      if not form.is_valid():
          # Handle error conditions here
          pass
      else:
          form.save()

      return HttpResponse('Your response')
```

Then, assuming it's bound to /import/, a GET to /import/?a=Test&b=1 would insert a new Foo with a = "Test" and b="1".

Comment: I don't want a form or any user interaction. The script that sends the data is run on a cron job overnight to update the database that Django uses for other things.